# React+Webpack+Babel: Module parse failed: Unexpected token "<"

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I'm setting up a React app (my first), and I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/) when I run webpack, I get the following error (pointing to the space immediately before the '<':

```
 PS C:\...\frontend> npm run dev

> frontend@1.0.0 dev C:\...\frontend
> webpack --mode development --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./build/frontend

asset main.js 4.77 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
runtime modules 937 bytes 4 modules
cacheable modules 1.34 KiB
  ./src/index.js 34 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/components/app.js 1.31 KiB [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/components/app.js 36:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (36:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     render() {
|         return(
>             <ul>
|                 {this.state.data.map(refugee => {
|                     return (
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-34

webpack 5.58.1 compiled with 1 error in 159 ms
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@1.0.0 dev: `webpack --mode development --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./build/frontend`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

As far as I can tell, it's a problem with babel not properly transpiling my `app.js` file, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it's throwing an error when it gets to the '<' (or maybe the space before the '<'?  IDK)

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./build/frontend",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./static/frontend"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-stage-3": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "expose-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "set-value": "^4.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.58.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const Path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const Webpack = require('webpack');
const { WebpackError } = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: Path.resolve(__dirname,'./src/index.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: Path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
    },
    resolve:{
        modules: [Path.join(__dirname,'src'), 'node_modules'],
        alias: {
            react:Path.join(__dirname,'node_modules','react'),
        }
    },
    optimization:{
        splitChunks:{
            chunks:'all',
            name:'vendors',
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: Path.resolve(__dirname,'./src/index.html')
        }),
        // new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        //     $:"jquery",
        //     jQuery:'jquery',
        //     Popper:['@popperjs/core','default']
        // }),
    
    ],
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'babel-loader',
                    'style-loader', 
                    "eslint-loader"
                ],
                query: {
                    presets:["@babel/react", "@babel/env"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'file-loader',
                  options: {
                    name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                loader: "expose-loader",
                options: {
                  exposes: ["$", "jQuery"],
                },
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's my `index.js`:

```
import App from "./components/app"
```

and my `app.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            loaded: false,
            placeholder: "loading"
        };
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("api/refugee")
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status >400) {
                    return this.setState(() => {
                        return { placeholder: "Something went wrong!"};
                    });
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.setState(() => {
                    return {
                        data,
                        loaded: true,
                    };
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.state.data.map(refugee => {
                    return (
                        <li key={refugee.id}>
                            {refugee.full_name}
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default App;

const container = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, container);
```

I am completely at a loss.

FWIW, here's a picture of my directory of my app
[image: App directory]

**Edit:**
On a whim, I tried completely removing the module.rules for `.js` files (instructing webpack to use `'babel-loader'`, and the error is *completely* the same.  Seems relevant, but I have no idea what it means...

**Edit 2:**
I forgot to include my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

**Edit 3:***
I tried 2 additional things:

1. I removed the portion of `app.js` that had `<`, and the error just pointed to the next `<` (at render(, container).  Webpack ran find when I removed that `<` as well.
2. I installed `babel-preset-2015` and added `ES2015` to my presets in `.babelrc`.  No change in the error message.

Comment: You may want to use a `.babelrc.js` file instead of trying to configure Babel in the Webpack configuration. (In fact, since you already have one, make sure it's correctly set up to reference those presets you've installed.)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that.  I forgot to upload my `.babelrc` file.  I updated my post with it.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use style-loader on your .js files... (eslint-loader is a bit iffy too; you can just run eslint otherwise)

Comment: I just removed `style-loader` and changed `eslint-loader` to `eslint` and no change.   I also tried just removing the entire `module.rules` section for `.js`, and it didn't make any difference.  It's like it's not even recognizing that particular section.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:  I had placed `webpack.config.js` in the folder `webpack/webpack.config.js`.  I still have no idea how to configure webpack to run if it's placed in a folder within the root directory.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You can point your webpack bundler at any config file by passing the path to the `--config=` arg in your package.json under the 'scripts' key. e.g. 
`"build": "webpack --mode production --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./static/frontend --config ./webpack/webpack.config.js"`